# How is this specific sound synthesized?

Tags: synthesizer, synthesis

Would like to know what kind of synthesizer, with what all type of controls might be used to synthesize the dominant instrument (obviously apart from purcussion, guitar) playing in this clip:

The clip is extracted from a youtube video of this Indian movie soundtrack (Note that I've placed a time-marker that starts to coincide with the clip in question):

The information section has all the other details (“Khamoshiyan” featuring Gurmeet Choudhary, Sapna Pabbi and Ali Fazal which is sung by Arijit Singh & composed by Jeet Gannguli).

Comment: Edited your linkified words so the auto-embed works. The clip sound very much like some heavily processed moog.. though a little too squary.

Answer (score 3):

Try 2 sawtooth oscillators on a mono synth with a small detune (perhaps just 1 cent) on one of the oscillators. Set a smooth but fairly quick attack and release for these oscillators. Send them through a low Pass filter around 3kHz or whatever sounds right, a slight envelope on the filter can sound good too.  Also, set a portamento/glide of roughly 35ms. The sound in the clip has a subtle pitch lfo too.
Add some subtle stereo delay, set to around 430ms and then some reverb.
 This should get you relatively close, then you can experiment and make it your own.